# Flutter - How do we achieve this UI using custom paint?

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-custompainter

I want to achieve attached UI widget using [custom paint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) or with any suitable way around which should work well across different device sizes. Currently, I'm achieving using it as a background image by exporting the image src but it doesn't work well across different device sizes (mostly in smaller sized device).

[image: this]

**Edited UI to**

[image]

Comment: try bezier Curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom paint like the following

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16/9,
        child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(),
            child: Container(),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

  class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
      Paint paint = Paint();
      Path path = Path();
  

      paint.color = Color(0xffFF0000);//<---change color here
      path = Path();
      path.lineTo(size.width * 0.9, 0);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.9, 0, size.width * 0.08, 0, size.width * 0.08, 0);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.02, 0, 0, size.height * 0.09, 0, size.height * 0.13);
      path.cubicTo(0, size.height * 0.13, 0, size.height * 0.9, 0, size.height * 0.9);
      path.cubicTo(0, size.height * 1.04, size.width * 0.06, size.height, size.width * 0.07, size.height * 0.96);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.11, size.height * 0.81, size.width * 0.16, size.height * 0.89, size.width * 0.18, size.height * 0.94);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.19, size.height, size.width * 0.23, size.height, size.width / 4, size.height);
      path.cubicTo(size.width / 4, size.height, size.width * 0.97, size.height, size.width * 0.97, size.height);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.98, size.height, size.width, size.height, size.width, size.height);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.97, size.width * 1.02, size.height * 0.91, size.width * 0.96, size.height * 0.87);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.91, size.height * 0.83, size.width * 0.92, size.height * 0.71, size.width * 0.96, size.height * 0.69);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.67, size.width, size.height * 0.57, size.width, size.height * 0.52);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.46, size.width, size.height * 0.29, size.width, size.height * 0.15);
      path.cubicTo(size.width, size.height * 0.01, size.width * 0.93, -0.01, size.width * 0.9, 0);
      path.cubicTo(size.width * 0.9, 0, size.width * 0.9, 0, size.width * 0.9, 0);
      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
    @override
    bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks for you time you saved my day. I just got the edited design (see edited question) and I tried to play around with your calculations but didn't get a similar match. Can you please edit your answer a bit so I can save my another day :)

Comment: A good solution is to export the svg and use an online tool to get its path

Comment: well, I tried with a few tools, they didn't export expected results :(